# How to upload ImageProvider's image to firebase storage in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, image, dart, firebase-storage

I am using this package [crop_image](https://pub.dev/packages/crop_image) to crop my image(This image is not been choosen from user's device, it is taken by the user through camera).

After the image is cropped it returns a Image Object

`final image = await controller.croppedImage(quality: FilterQuality.medium);`

this Image object gives ImageProvider

`image.image`

I want to upload this cropped image to firebase storage but I can't convert this image or the ImageProvider into File, Uri or bytes.

I have been trying to find a solution for hours but it seem no one has faced this issue.

Answer (score 1):

So, if you read that package description closely, then in the last paragraph they have explained that how to convert to a file

rather than this

```
Image image = await controller.croppedImage();
```

You need to do this

```
ui.Image bitmap = await controller.croppedBitmap();
```

Creating a file

If you want to save the cropped ui.Image to a file, this operation is not specific to this plugin. Use the existing functions of ui.Image and File:

```
data = await bitmap.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
bytes = data!.buffer.asUint8List();
file.writeAsBytes(bytes, flush);
```

OR YOU CAN USE THIS PACKAGE

https://pub.dev/packages/image_cropper